# Amazon Rekognition for text dertection text in image

Tags: android, apache, android-studio, amazon-rekognition

I have an error about getting text in image using `Amazon Rekognition` service

```
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 32656
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:146)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:86)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:63)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:56)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:50)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:38)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:317)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:301)
        at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:194)
        at com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognitionClient.<init>(AmazonRekognitionClient.java:290)
        at com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.build(AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.java:61)
        at com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.build(AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.java:27)
        at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
        at com.amazonaws.services.rekognition.AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.defaultClient(AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.java:45)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5368)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is my code

```
String photo = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/test/testImage.png";

    ByteBuffer imageBytes;
        try  {

            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(photo));
            imageBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
            Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(Level.FINEST);
            Logger.getLogger("com.amazonaws").setLevel(Level.FINEST);

            ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(photo)
                    .into(imageView);

                  AmazonRekognition rekognitionClient = AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.defaultClient();


            DetectTextRequest  request = new DetectTextRequest ()
                    .withImage(new Image()
                            .withBytes(imageBytes));



            DetectTextResult  result = rekognitionClient.detectText(request);
            List<TextDetection> textDetections = result.getTextDetections();

            Log.i(TAG,"Detected lines and words for " + photo);
                for (TextDetection  text: textDetections) {

                    Log.i(TAG,"Detected: " + text.getDetectedText());
                    Log.i(TAG,"Confidence: " + text.getConfidence().toString());


                }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
        }
```

I tried using library 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6' and 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.6' but for httpclient 'gradle' can't resolve its dependencies.

Did I write something wrong ? also can i use Text in image to get image from local storage ? and does it support Arabic or not ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation the current algorithm can only recognize,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet

Upper and Lower case English characters.

**Text Detection:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/text-detection.html

> A word is one or more ISO basic Latin script characters that aren't
>   separated by spaces. DetectText can detect up to 50 words in an image.

Arabic is not supported yet as of this writing.

Hope it helps.